# Why doesn't GCC produce a warning when assigning a signed literal to an unsigned type?

Tags: c, gcc, unsigned, gcc-warning

Several questions on this website reveal pitfalls when mixing signed and unsigned types and most compilers seem to do a good job about generating warnings of this type.  However, GCC doesn't seem to care when assigning a signed constant to an unsigned type!  Consider the following program:

```
/* foo.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x=20, y=-30;
    if (x > y) {
        printf("%d > %d\n", x, y);
    } else {
        printf("%d <= %d\n", x, y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation with GCC 4.2.1 as below produces no output on the console:

```
gcc -Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic foo.c -o foo
```

The resulting executable generates the following output:

```
$ ./foo
20 <= -30
```

Is there some reason that GCC doesn't generate any warning or error message when assigning the signed value `-30` to the unsigned integer variable `y`?

Comment: Note that you should use %u for printing `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Bastien, indeed; perhaps more interesting is that, as AndreyT pointed out in his answer below, `printf("%d")` shows the signed value instead of the unsigned value (4294967266) which is used by the comparison operator!

Comment: It's because of the 2's complement representation of signed int: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement (this representation isn't guaranteed by the C standard, but in practice I've never heard of another representation being still in use)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [-Wconversion](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wclobbered-379):

```
~/src> gcc -Wconversion -Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o signwarn signwarn.c
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
signwarn.c: In function 'main':
signwarn.c:5: error: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type
```

I guess the thing here is that gcc is actually pretty good at generating warnings, but it defaults to not doing so for (sometimes unexpected) cases. It's a good idea to browse through the available warnings and choose a set of options that generate those you feel would help. Or just all of them, and polish that code until it shines! :)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Makes me wish there existed a `Wallall` ;)

Comment: Note that `-Wsign-conversion` is _not_ enabled by default under `-Wconversion` in C++ so better always add it explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

The ability to convert negative value to unsigned type is a *feature* of C language. For this reason, the warning is not issued by default. You have to request it explicitly, if you so desire.

As for what your program outputs... Using `%d` format specifier of `printf` with an unsigned value that lies beyond the range of type `int` results in undefined behavior, which is what you really observed in your experiment.

Comment: Hey, good catch. `printf("%d", y);` is in a whole other category than `y=-30;`.

Comment: Great point, I could imagine using a negative value to create a desired bitfield, for example.

Comment: Yep - conversion of negative #'s to unsigned is defined to produce a result 'modulo' the size of the unsigned int, so (unsigned)-1 is a perfectly good way of saying "an unsigned with all 1's in it". When signed numbers are represented with 2's complement, this 'conversion' is simply the same bit pattern as the signed.

Answer (score 2):

Using (unsigned)-1 is an often used way to set all bits and sometimes even quoted as reason for this (mis)feature of C, even by people who should know better
.  It's neither obvious nor portable -- the expression you want to use to set all bits is ~0 .

Comment: I consider the meaning of "uint32_t x=-1;` obvious, the Standard specifies the precise behavior, and it's more portable than would be `uint32_t x=~0;` or `uint32_t x=~0u;` [on a sign-magnitude system, the `~0` form would set `x` to 0xFFFF8001ul; on any 16-bit system, the `~0u` form would set `x` to 0x0000FFFFul; the form using `-1` will work on any system which defines `uint32_t`.]