# Is there a way to make GCC alert me when I provide a signed integer to function that accepts only unsigned one?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, unsigned-integer

This code gives me no warnings when compiled with `g++`:

```
unsigned int myFunc(unsigned int integer) {
  return integer;
}
int main() {
  int x = -1;
  std::cout << myFunc(x) << std::endl;
}
```

It compiles fine but the result is wrong: `4294967295`. Does GCC have any compiler `-W*` options for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't GCC produce a warning when assigning a signed literal to an unsigned type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771538/why-doesnt-gcc-produce-a-warning-when-assigning-a-signed-literal-to-an-unsigned)

Comment: Don't tag a C++ question as C.

Comment: This question is now unambiguously not a dupe, since the C tag has been removed, the other question is about C only, and the answers on the other question don't work here. Arguably that question could be marked a dupe of this one I suppose, since the answers here work for C :-)

Comment: I was about to say what Steve Jessop said: I don't think this is a duplicate of the other since one is for C and the other for C++.  They're closely related, but not duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `-Wsign-conversion`

Beware that `-Wconversion` doesn't enable this warning for C++ code, although it does for C code.

Answer (score 4):

There is a small caveat that I should probably outline since it can be kinda tricky and easily confused.

When compiling `C` code `-Wconversion` is usually enough, since it triggers a couple of other flags automatically.

When compiling `C++` code `-Wconversion` doesn't triggers the exact same flags as `gcc` does in `C`, so you should use `-Wsign-conversion -Wconversion`

[Link to the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).