# Shouldn't C++ compiler issue a warning for literal to negative number conversions

Tags: c++

I made a very silly mistake in the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int ARR_SIZE = 2147483648;
    int* intarr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * ARR_SIZE);
    for(int i =0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        intarr[i] = i;
    }
}
```

So I really should have used an unsigned int for ARR_SIZE. 2147483648 when assigned to a signed 32-bit int is really the largest negative number. 
Is there a good reason why the compiler doesn't (or shouldn't) issue a warning for this. Should I require an explicit cast when assigning a positive literal that is larger than a types maximum value? (For the case where I really wanted a negative number)

(Source language was C++ when I ran into this but I think this is just as much a C question).

This was with g++ 6.1.1 and compiled as such:

```
g++ -Wall -g -o test_so test_so.cpp
```

Comment: The size of `int` is mainly platform dependent.

Comment: Question is missing compiler version and compilation options.

Comment: Regarding "positive literal": there are no "negative literals".

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks, fixed.

Comment: The answer to question "should it" is "no it shouldn't", at least according to the standard.

Comment: Note that the literal doesn't have type `int`, it has whatever type necessary to represent the value (but at least `int`). The initialization then causes a conversion from that type to the type of the variable that's being initialized. (But I agree that a warning would be nice. Luckily, [GCC already has this warning](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OWasZMuH8NoUlMmh).)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Surely the compiler knows the size of types on the platform on which you are compiling?

Comment: [-Wconversion warns it for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771538/why-doesnt-gcc-produce-a-warning-when-assigning-a-signed-literal-to-an-unsigned)

Comment: This is routinely signaled with -Wextra (which you should really enable always).

Comment: @MatteoItalia no, -Wextra alone doesn't report this (I agree on enabling it tho).

Comment: @Ohashi That works, thank you!

Comment: @Ohashi: wops, probably then -Wconversion is included in my "standard warnings set", not in -Wextra.

Comment: "*So I really should have used an unsigned int*" yes, namely `size_t`. It is made for exactly this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the switch `-Wconversion` to `gcc`, you will get the following warning on ILP32, LP64, LLP64 platforms:

```
test.c:5:26: error: conversion to ‘int’ alters ‘long int’ constant value
                    [-Werror=conversion]
    const int ARR_SIZE = 2147483648;
```

This warning flag is *not* included in either `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.

---

Also do note that an integer literal always has a type that is large enough to contain it, but at least `int`, on C. (On C++, a character literal will have type `char` instead!). In this case 2147483648 is of type `long int`, as on this platform `long int` has 64 bits (LP64); on Windows (LLP64) it would be a `long long int'.

Quoting the holy book (n1570),

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented

and for suffixless decimal literals, the list is `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`.

Comment: Thanks Antii. Great answer. I noticed that when I use the literal 0x10000000 instead that I no longer get this warning even with -Wconversion. This makes sense because as you say it's common to represent negative numbers as hexadecimal literals.

Comment: @Avatar33 now this is overflow, it is caught with `-Wall`. You meant perhaps `0x80000000`. That is caught with `-Wconversion` and also `-Wsign-conversion`, because hexadecimal constants are unsigned.

Comment: 0x10000000 (7 trailing zeros) isn't an overflow but I mean't 0x80000000 yes.

Comment: ahh :D I read that as 8 zeroes, yes, which would give a warning with `-Wall` alone.